# Does Dagashi Kashi author getting paid for advertise snack in her manga?

Tags: anime-production, manga-production, dagashi-kashi

The series Dagashi Kashi is like an advertise manga, it's promoted many snacks for children from japan. Does DagashiKashi's mangaka getting paid for promoted all of those snack?

I mean did all of those snacks which appear in DagashiKashi series (manga and anime) have been affiliated before between the mangaka and many snacks company ?

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know, there aren't any candy companies in the production committee or officially listed in the sponsor page.

One of the main purposes of the manga is to talk about Dagashiya and their decline in Japan, as their role is taken over by more general convenience stores and supermarkets. It's a nostalgic trip down memory lane. Not naming specific candies would destroy that purpose.